# capistrano - NameError: uninitialized constant Net::SSH::KnownHosts::SUPPORTED_TYPE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my Rails (3.1.3) application to the preprod env.
I use capistrano (2.12.0) and rvm-capistrano (1.2.2).

When I call `bundle exec cap ssh` it works fine.
But when I call `bundle exec cap deploy` I get the following trace:

```
$ cap deploy
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy'
  * 18:42:19 == Currently executing `multistage:ensure'
*** Defaulting to `preprod'
  * 18:42:19 == Currently executing `preprod'
  * 18:42:19 == Currently executing `deploy'
  * 18:42:19 == Currently executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 18:42:19 == Currently executing `deploy:update_code'
  * 18:42:19 == Currently executing `deploy:set_previous_revision'
  * executing "cd /rails_apps/com.example.preprod/current; git rev-parse --short HEAD"
    servers: ["preprod.example.com"]
connection failed for: preprod.example.com (NameError: uninitialized constant Net::SSH::KnownHosts::SUPPORTED_TYPE)
```

Of course `example.com` is a placeholder, it doesn't come from a mistake in the capistrano config.

Any idea of what could cause that ?

I'm using RVM with Ruby 1.9.3-p194.

Thanks !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reverting back from net-ssh 2.5.1 to 2.4.0 seems to solve the problem for now.

Comment: Also, if you're downgrading and/or pointing to the fix in the branch noted below, make sure you run cap with `bundle exec cap deploy` otherwise bundler will pick up the 2.5.1 version you have installed already.

Comment: Just in case anyone wants the cheat sheat:


    `$ gem uninstall net-ssh`

    `Select gem to uninstall:`
    ` 1. net-ssh-2.3.0`
    ` 2. net-ssh-2.5.1`
    ` 3. All versions`
    `> 2`
    `Successfully uninstalled net-ssh-2.5.1`

Comment: fixed as of 2.5.2. run `bundle update` to get latest version or specify the specific version in your Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

I installed rvm-capistrano gem to solved this problem:

`gem install rvm-capistrano`