# Error: while bootstrapping using knife on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra, knife

I am trying to bootstrap a node using my Ubuntu workstation on which is installed the Chef 10.12.0 tried it using 11.10 but the same error. And the node is ubuntu. I can ssh to it just find but while trying to bootstrap using knife it throws me some error.

This error message "Exception: NameError: uninitialized constant Net::SSH::Compat" has made me to things like uninstalling and reinstalling ssh, upgrading downgrading ruby, ssh but to no use. but I seem to have caught the cause of it in the verbose mode, which is of the incompatibilty of the ssh clients? And not sure on what is the best way of fixing them.

```
vm@vm:~/chef-repo$ knife bootstrap 127.0.0.1 --sudo -x vagrant -P vagrant -p 2222 -N "vm1"
Bootstrapping Chef on 127.0.0.1
ERROR: knife encountered an unexpected error
This may be a bug in the 'bootstrap' knife command or plugin
Please collect the output of this command with the `-VV` option before filing a bug report.
Exception: NameError: uninitialized constant Net::SSH::Compat
vm@vm:~/chef-repo$ knife bootstrap 127.0.0.1 --sudo -x vagrant -P vagrant -p 2222 -N "vm1" -VV
DEBUG: Looking for bootstrap template in /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.0/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap
DEBUG: Found bootstrap template in /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.10.0/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap
Bootstrapping Chef on 127.0.0.1
DEBUG: Adding 127.0.0.1
DEBUG: establishing connection to 127.0.0.1:2222
DEBUG: connection established
INFO: negotiating protocol version
DEBUG: remote is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1'
DEBUG: local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_2.8.0 x86_64-linux'
ERROR: knife encountered an unexpected error
This may be a bug in the 'bootstrap' knife command or plugin
Please collect the output of this command with the `-VV` option before filing a bug report.
Exception: NameError: uninitialized constant Net::SSH::Compat
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [capistrano - NameError: uninitialized constant Net::SSH::KnownHosts::SUPPORTED\_TYPE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741936/capistrano-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-netsshknownhostssupported-t)